# dynamic jquery validation not working correclty

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

hi i am trying to dynamically validate my registration form, so that check are being made, when the user enters values into input fields using jquery and php. i am returning the values using a json array, the first input box is validated but the second one does not get validated and im not sure why? any help would be mostly appreciated.

Comment: When you call validate use: validate($('#fname').val(),$('#lname').val());

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This problem is occurring because your `validate()` function takes two parameters: `fname` and `name`, but you are always only sending the first parameter and not the other one.

To fix it, in your `fname` events do this:

```
validate($('#fname').val() , "");
          ---------------    ---
                 |            |
               fname        lname
```

and in your `lname` events do this:

```
validate("" , $('#lname').val());
         ---  ----------------
          |            |
        fname        lname
```

and in your `PHP` make sure you set it so that it reads no "blanks":

```
if( isset($_POST['lname']) && $_POST['lname'] !== "")

if( isset($_POST['fname']) && $_POST['fname'] !== "")
```

Comment: when i enter information into the first input box it is validating my lname input box as well

Comment: should it do that, or not?

Comment: ok i made an edit, thats probably happening because you are sending blanks